# Auto set minimum and maximum value on textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I want to make the textbox automatically set the maximum value when the user put the value above the maximum value. Example min is 0 and max is 255. When user put 999 in the textbox, it automatically set to 255 as the max value. When user put -11 on textbox, it automatically set to 0 as the min value. You can see the gif animation below how it should work

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Tqg.gif]

I had tried `if else` statement but it could not convert string to `int`.

Comment: Or use a `NumericUpDown`, which is made specifically for the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should set this on every text box you want this functionality for.

it simply check for `Text` of the textbox if it is numerical then it checks for ranges and apply appropriate value

```
yourtextbox.TextChanged+= (s, e) =>
{
    var textbox = s as TextBox;
    int value;
    if (int.TryParse(textbox.Text, out value))
    {
        if (value > 255)
            textbox.Text = "255";
        else if (value < 0)
            textbox.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: @dotctor What if minimum is 5 and you what to type 15? You will not be able to do it because the moment you type 1 the validation will fail and you will not be able to type the 5.

Answer (score 3):

Use the textbox's ontextchange event
In the event check:

```
if (int.Parse(textBox.Text) > MAX_VALUE) {
    textBox.Text = MAX_VALUE;
}
```