# Setting value of a textfield to not go lower than zero

Tags: c#, winforms

How do i set a textfield so it cant go lower than 0?

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to give some sort of clue what framework you're using.

Comment: This is just a basic Windows form c#

Comment: What do you mean by "cant go lower than 0"? Can it store non-numbers? I guess, yes. Is it readonly? If yes, then you don't need this logic. If no, then what should happen if user enters letter?

Comment: Not sure how this all works, but I assume that some method is executing when pressing UP or DOWN button. Just configure those methods to make text>int, int-- or ++, int>text, update textfield. And if int == 0, do nothing when pressed DOWN.

Comment: I think this is going to help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26828417/5094336

Comment: Use `NumericUpDown` instead of text field and set `Minimum = 0` or handle texfield value on keypress event

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows Forms you can simply use the [`NumericUpDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx), it also exposes [`Minimum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.minimum(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Maximum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx) value fields.

If for some reason you will need to roll your own, you will probably need to attach yourself to the event which is fired when the text is changed. If the content of the text field is numeric and is lower than 0, then simply override the text with `0` or whatever value you wish to provide.

Answer (score 0):

`win form` code :-

```
private void btnArrowUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int val = 0;
   if (Convert.ToInt32(textBoxValue.Text) <= 1000) //convert the textBox value to integer and check for your Upper Limit (here i have set it to 1000)
   {
        // if so, increment by your step (i used 1)
        val = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxValue.Text);
        val += 1;
        textBoxValue.Text = val.ToString();
        labelErrorMessage.Visible = false;
   }
   else
   {
        // otherwise, give a message and reset to your Default (i used 0)
        textBoxValue.Text = "0";
        labelErrorMessage.Text = "1000 (Zero) is the Max limit !";
        labelErrorMessage.Visible = true;
   }
 }

 private void btnArrowDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int val = 0;
    if (Convert.ToInt32(textBoxValue.Text) > 0) //convert the textBox value to integer and check for your Lower Limit (here i have set it to 0)
    {
        // if so, decrement by your step (i used 1)
        val = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxValue.Text);
        val -= 1;
        textBoxValue.Text = val.ToString();
        labelErrorMessage.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise, give a message and reset to your Default (i used 0)
        textBoxValue.Text = "0";
        labelErrorMessage.Text = "0 (Zero) is the lowest limit !";
        labelErrorMessage.Visible = true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NumericUpDown` instead of text field and set `Minimum = 0` or follow this

Add Balloon.cs

```
public enum TooltipIcon
{
    None,
    Info,
    Warning,
    Error
}
public class Balloon
{
    private Control m_parent;
    private string m_text = "FMS Balloon Tooltip Control Display Message";
    private string m_title = "FMS Balloon Tooltip Message";
    private TooltipIcon m_titleIcon = TooltipIcon.None;
    private const int ECM_FIRST = 0x1500;
    private const int EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP = ECM_FIRST + 3;
    [DllImport("User32", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(
        IntPtr hWnd,
        int Msg,
        int wParam,
        IntPtr lParam);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private struct EDITBALLOONTIP
    {
        public int cbStruct;
        public string pszTitle;
        public string pszText;
        public int ttiIcon;
    }
    public Balloon()
    {
    }
    public Balloon(Control parent)
    {
        m_parent = parent;
    }
    public void Show()
    {
        EDITBALLOONTIP ebt = new EDITBALLOONTIP();
        ebt.cbStruct = Marshal.SizeOf(ebt);
        ebt.pszText = m_text;
        ebt.pszTitle = m_title;
        ebt.ttiIcon = (int)m_titleIcon;
        IntPtr ptrStruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ebt));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(ebt, ptrStruct, false);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(m_parent != null, "Parent control is null", "Set parent before calling Show");
        int ret = SendMessage(m_parent.Handle, EM_SHOWBALLOONTIP, 0, ptrStruct);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrStruct);
    }
    public void Show(string text, Control parent, string title, TooltipIcon icon)
    {

    }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return m_title;
        }
        set
        {
            m_title = value;
        }
    }
    public TooltipIcon TitleIcon
    {
        get
        {
            return m_titleIcon;
        }
        set
        {
            m_titleIcon = value;
        }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return m_text;
        }
        set
        {
            m_text = value;
        }
    }
    public Control Parent
    {
        get
        {
            return m_parent;
        }
        set
        {
            m_parent = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following code to your Form

```
private readonly Balloon _balloonTip = new Balloon();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = HandledNumerics(sender, e);
    }
    private bool HandledNumerics(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var handled = !(Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Delete));
        if (handled)
        {
            ShowBalloon("Warning", "Invalid Input!\nOnly numeric value is acceptable", (TextBox)sender);
        }
        return handled;
    }
    private void ShowBalloon(string title, string text, Control parent, TooltipIcon icon = TooltipIcon.Warning)
    {
        _balloonTip.Title = title;
        _balloonTip.Text = text;
        _balloonTip.Parent = parent;
        _balloonTip.TitleIcon = icon;
        _balloonTip.Show();
    }
```

And get the result just like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simple way, just create a funcion that verifies is the value is bellow 0 and call it when the text changes, or in your down_click function if the text field is locked to keybord input.

```
private void bellowZero()
{
     if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) < 0)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "0";
    }
}
```